# Is there a function I can use to replace my if statements and variables?

Tags: python, cs50

I'm trying to figure out how to make my code more readable and have less lines in my code. It contains a lot of if elif statements that seem like can be combined into a few.

```
fl = input("file:").lower().strip()

a = fl.endswith(".jpeg")
b = fl.endswith(".jpg")
c = fl.endswith(".txt")
d = fl.endswith(".png")
e = fl.endswith(".pdf")
f = fl.endswith(".zip")
g = fl.endswith(".gif")

if a or b is True:
    print("image/jpeg")
elif c is True:
    print("text/plain")
elif d is True:
    print("image/png")
elif e is True:
    print("application/pdf")
elif f is True:
    print("application/zip")
elif g is True:
    print("image/gif")
else:
    print("application/octet-stream")
```

I tried getting rid of the variables on the top by putting `fl == fl.endswith(".filetype")` inside of the if statements, and instead of printing each type it only printed my else statement. I also tried looking up other ways to get the end of the str in python docs but couldn't find anything. Don't give me too direct of a solution to the problem, would like to avoid cs50 academic honesty issues. Also still quite new to python

Comment: The first simplest step is to remove all the `is True`s. Python `if` statements already check for true, you don't need to add extra steps to that. Then you can _inline_ the variables. Rather than `c = fl.endswith(".txt") ... elif c is True`, you can just write: `elif fl.endswith(".txt")`

Comment: yeah idk why I included all of those lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dictionary to map extensions to content-types.

```py
import os

extension_content_types = {
    ".jpeg": "image/jpeg",
    ".jpg": "image/jpeg",
    ".txt": "text/plain",
    ".png": "image/png",
    ".pdf": "application/pdf",
    ".zip": "application/zip",
    ".gif": "image/gif",
}

fl = input("file:").lower().strip()
filename, ext = os.path.splitext(fl)
content_type = extension_content_types.get(ext, 'application/octet-stream')

print(fl, content_type)
```

Comment: You can alternatively use `pathlib.Path(fl).suffix` to get the file extension.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary:

```py
extensions = {
    "image/jpeg": (".jpeg", ".jpg"),
    "text/plain": (".txt",),
    "image/png": (".png",),
    "application/pdf": (".pdf",),
    "application/zip": (".zip",),
    "image/gif": (".gif",),
}

expected_mime_type = "application/octet-stream"
for mime_type, extensions in extensions.items():
    if fl.endswith(extensions):  # <- can use multiple here
        expected_mime_type = mime_type
        break

print(expected_mime_type)
```

Comment: Downvoted. Iterating through all the key-value pairs of a dict to match a value for a key defeats the very purpose of a dict. If you're matching by file extensions, make file extensions the key for *O(1)*-time lookups.

Comment: The right way to do this would be to make a config dict like yours, but then programmatically convert it to the one in @sytech's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77526585/6890912) to perform lookups. Please also watch your language.

Comment: What are you talking about? Your code literally requires *O(n)* in time complexity where *n* is the number of content types.

Comment: @blhsing The content types are *not* the input, and you know that. The input is `fl`. Complexity is about the input.

Comment: And yet to perform a lookup you require a loop over the length of the dict. A completely unnecessary overhead no matter in which way you slice it.

Comment: @blhsing Your "right way to do this" also would loop over the length of the dict. As I said, it depends *a lot* on what the OP would do. That guy's answer is an alternative, my answer is another.

Comment: @blhsing Is common sense to assume that doubling the space complexity by creating two dictionaries is always the right way to do it?

Comment: The config dict can be deleted right after the conversion in case you did not know.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably better to use existing `mimetypes` package than maintaining a custom mapping

```
import mimetypes
mimetypes.init()

for t in ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'pdf', 'zip', 'txt', 'png', 'gif', 'lmc']:
    mt = "application/octet-stream"
    if f".{t}" in mimetypes.types_map.keys():
        mt = mimetypes.types_map[f'.{t}']
    print(f"{t:4}: {mt}")
```

result

```
jpg : image/jpeg
jpeg: image/jpeg
pdf : application/pdf
zip : application/zip
txt : text/plain
png : image/png
gif : image/gif
lmc : application/octet-stream
```

Comment: Those three lines can be simplified to `mt = mimetypes.types_map.get("." + t, "application/octet-stream")`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest/cleanest to create a dictionary that maps file extensions to content types:

```
extensions = {
    '.jpeg': 'image/jpeg',
    '.jpg': 'image/jpeg',
    '.txt': 'text/plain',
    # etc etc etc
}

for extension, content_type in extensions.items():
    if fl.endswith(extension):
        print(content_type)
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I'm trying to figure out how to make my code more readable and have less lines in my code. ..."*

Ideally, you'll want to categorize the data, into components.

```py
ext = [['.jpeg', '.jpg'], '.txt', '.png', '.pdf', '.zip', '.gif']
mime = ['image/jpeg', 'text/plain', 'image/png', 'application/pdf', 'application/zip', 'image/gif', 'application/octet-stream']
M = zip(ext, mime)
fl = input("file:").lower().strip()
for t in M:
    if fl in str(t): print(t)
```

Output

```
file:jpg
(['.jpeg', '.jpg'], 'image/jpeg')
```

Although, I recommend utilizing the *[mimetypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html)* module; specifically, the *[types_map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.types_map)* *dictionary*.

```py
import mimetypes as m
fl = input("file:").lower().strip()
for t in m.types_map.items():
   if fl in str(t): print(t)
```

Output

```
file:jpg
('.jpg', 'image/jpeg')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want brevity:

```
types_by_extension = {
    "jpeg" : "image/jpeg", "jpg" : "image/jpeg", ".txt" : "text/plain",
    "png" : "image/png", "pdf" : "application/pdf",
    "zip" : "application/zip", "gif" : "image/gif"}

assert("." in f1)
f1_ext = f1.split(".")[1]
print(types_by_extension.get(f1_ext, "application/octet-stream"))
```

The `get` method will look up the `dict` and fallback to the default of octet-stream if it can't find a match.

Comment: Consider that a filename may have multiple `.` characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a dictionary to store the different file types as keys and their respective outputs that you want to print as values.

You can then just check if:

```
fl[-4:] in _dict or fl[-5:] in _dict
```

And then print the corresponding key from the dictionary.